How to prevent flickering caused by cls in a batch script?
I have been working on a batch script which has some sort of animated intro, My first thought was to use cls to clear the console before every frame, but that caused horrible flickering, as shown in this video https://streamable.com/o34k0e.
this is the batch code I used:
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::
:loop
cls
for /L %%A in (1,1,20) do (
    cls
    call :frame %%A
    ping -n 1 -w 300 127.0.0.1 >nul
)
goto loop

goto :eof

:frame
:: full letters
set "letters1=  █     █░▓█████  ██▓     ▄████▄   ▒█████   ███▄ ▄███▓▓█████"
set "letters2= ▓█░ █ ░█░▓█   ▀ ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█  ▒██▒  ██▒▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒▓█   ▀"
set "letters3= ▒█░ █ ░█ ▒███   ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄ ▒██░  ██▒▓██    ▓██░▒███"
set "letters4= ░█░ █ ░█ ▒▓█  ▄ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒▒██   ██░▒██    ▒██ ▒▓█  ▄"
set "letters5= ░░██▒██▓ ░▒████▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░░ ████▓▒░▒██▒   ░██▒░▒████▒"
set "letters6= ░ ▓░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░ ░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒░   ░  ░░░ ▒░ ░"
set "letters7=   ▒ ░ ░   ░ ░  ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒     ░ ▒ ▒░ ░  ░      ░ ░ ░  ░"
set "letters8=   ░   ░     ░     ░ ░   ░        ░ ░ ░ ▒  ░      ░      ░"
set "letters9=     ░       ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░          ░ ░         ░      ░  ░"
set "letters10=                         ░"

:: play dripping effect by changing characters in the lines 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
if %1 lss 5 (
    set "letters5=%letters5:▒= %"
) else if %1 lss 10 (
    set "letters6=%letters6:░= %"
) else if %1 lss 15 (
    set "letters7=%letters7:▒= %"
) else if %1 lss 20 (
    set "letters8=%letters8:░= %"
) else if %1 lss 25 (
    set "letters9=%letters9:▓= %"
)

:: display the letters with the "dripping" effect
echo.
echo !letters1!
echo !letters2!
echo !letters3!
echo !letters4!
if defined letters5 echo !letters5!
if defined letters6 echo !letters6!
if defined letters7 echo !letters7!
if defined letters8 echo !letters8!
if defined letters9 echo !letters9!
echo !letters10!
goto :eof


And I also tried using PowerShell which also failed to even display a second frame, as seen here:
# UTF-8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

# define the letters for the animation
$lines = @(
    "  █     █░▓█████  ██▓     ▄████▄   ▒█████   ███▄ ▄███▓▓█████",
    " ▓█░ █ ░█░▓█   ▀ ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█  ▒██▒  ██▒▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒▓█   ▀",
    " ▒█░ █ ░█ ▒███   ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄ ▒██░  ██▒▓██    ▓██░▒███",
    " ░█░ █ ░█ ▒▓█  ▄ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒▒██   ██░▒██    ▒██ ▒▓█  ▄",
    " ░░██▒██▓ ░▒████▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░░ ████▓▒░▒██▒   ░██▒░▒████▒",
    " ░ ▓░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░ ░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒░   ░  ░░░ ▒░ ░",
    "   ▒ ░ ░   ░ ░  ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒     ░ ▒ ▒░ ░  ░      ░ ░ ░  ░",
    "   ░   ░     ░     ░ ░   ░        ░ ░ ░ ▒  ░      ░      ░  ░",
    "     ░       ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░          ░ ░         ░      ░  ░",
    "                         ░"
)

# loop for animation
while ($true) {
    # clear the console
    Clear-Host

    # loop through each line to create the dripping effect
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++) {
        $line = $lines[$i]
        
        # changq certain characters based on their index
        if ($i -ge 4 -and $i -lt 9) {
            if ($i -eq 4) { $line = $line -replace '▒', ' ' }
            elseif ($i -eq 5) { $line = $line -replace '░', ' ' }
            elseif ($i -eq 6) { $line = $line -replace '▒', ' ' }
            elseif ($i -eq 7) { $line = $line -replace '░', ' ' }
            elseif ($i -eq 8) { $line = $line -replace '▓', ' ' }
        }
        
        # the modified line
        Write-Host $line
    }

    # wait before refreshing the display
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
}


Batch code to execute the PowerShell file:
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0drip-animation.ps1"
pause



Does your terminal device provide a move cursor to top left (or position x,y) escape code? IOW don't clear the screen with CLS in the loop. Jump back to the top left corner and overwrite the previously displayed screen with the next animation frame.

My advice is don't bother. We are not seven year olds, and aren't excited by moving pictures any more, nor do we care if you welcome us. Just use Echo WELCOME, followed by %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 1>NUL if you really do want them to have time to read that message.

It is probably the PING statement.  Try removing and see what happens.   The ping statement is just creating a delay to keep message on screen before the cls removes the text.  The flicking occurs because the screen goes blank when the cls and the code takes time to recreate the message.  Increasing the time message stay on screen by increasing the w will reduce the flickering but slow down the speed the message.

Removing the PING statement does not work. As for removing cls, I’m pretty sure that the windows cmd does not support ANSI escape codes. Unless I'm completely wrong

If you follow @martinbrown’s suggestion, you could also potentially render the entire animation frame into a single string with embedded line breaks and write that with one call to write-host so you don’t see all the incremental line writes…

@Marios: ANSI escape sequences are supported since windows 10, not all, not perfect, but for your case there are the SetCursor with ESC[H, disable cursor ESC[?25l and enable cursor ESC[?25h. Turning off the cursor is useful to avoid flickering when writing.



You can solve the problem in PowerShell with the help of the [Console] .NET API, as shown below.

The key to avoiding flickering is to use [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, 0) to set the cursor back in the top-left corner before writing the next animation frame, which doesn't require clearing the whole screen first (cls, Clear-Host).


To use this solution, you neither need chcp 65001 >nul in your wrapper batch file, nor [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 in the PowerShell script (in PowerShell, [Console]::OutputEncoding only matters with respect to communicating with external programs).

However, be sure to save your *.ps1 file as UTF-8 with BOM, so that Windows PowerShell reads the file correctly (PowerShell (Core) 7, which consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, would also read a BOM-less UTF-8 file correctly.



# Define the lines for the animation
$lines = @'
  █     █░▓█████  ██▓     ▄████▄   ▒█████   ███▄ ▄███▓▓█████
 ▓█░ █ ░█░▓█   ▀ ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█  ▒██▒  ██▒▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒▓█   ▀
 ▒█░ █ ░█ ▒███   ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄ ▒██░  ██▒▓██    ▓██░▒███
 ░█░ █ ░█ ▒▓█  ▄ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒▒██   ██░▒██    ▒██ ▒▓█  ▄
 ░░██▒██▓ ░▒████▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░░ ████▓▒░▒██▒   ░██▒░▒████▒
 ░ ▓░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░ ░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒░   ░  ░░░ ▒░ ░
   ▒ ░ ░   ░ ░  ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒     ░ ▒ ▒░ ░  ░      ░ ░ ░  ░
   ░   ░     ░     ░ ░   ░        ░ ░ ░ ▒  ░      ░      ░  ░
     ░       ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░          ░ ░         ░      ░  ░
                         ░
'@ -split '\r?\n'

[Console]::Clear()
[Console]::CursorVisible = $false

foreach ($i in 1..20) {

  [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, 0)

  [Console]::Write($lines -join "`n")

  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300

  if ($i -lt 5) { $lines[4] = $lines[4] -replace '▒', ' ' }
  elseif ($i -lt 10) { $lines[5] = $lines[5] -replace '░', ' ' }
  elseif ($i -lt 15) { $lines[6] = $lines[6] -replace '▒', ' ' }
  elseif ($i -lt 20) { $lines[7] = $lines[7] -replace '░', ' ' }
  elseif ($i -lt 25) { $lines[8] = $lines[8] -replace '▓', ' ' }

}
[Console]::CursorVisible = $true

